# Spaceship operator with pimpl idiom

Tags: c++, c++20, pimpl-idiom, spaceship-operator

I have a class that uses the pimpl idiom.

```cpp
class MyImpl;

class MyClass
{
public:

private:
    MyImpl* _impl;
};
```

Now I'd like to add spaceship operator support to this class. Ideally I would write something like:

```cpp
auto operator<=>(const MyClass& rhs) const
{
    return *_impl <=> *rhs._impl;
}
```

The implementation is not known in the header file though. Hence, I have to write the implementation in the source file. But that prevents the usage of `auto` as a return type. I have to be explicit on whether it's `std::strong_ordering`, `std::weak_ordering` or `std::partial_ordering`. But that heavily depends on the details of `MyImpl`. If `MyImpl` contains only `int`s, the return type would be `std::strong_ordering`, but if it would contain `float`s too it would be `std::partial_ordering`.

I'd like the class declaration of `MyClass` not to change too much. What's a way to keep its api stable, while still allowing changing member types of `MyImpl`. I guess it's not ideal to just always return `std::partial_ordering`.

Comment: This is the point of PIMPL, isn't it? The header isn't affected when the class members change. You have to choose the ordering category manually.

Comment: Can't you do something like `return _impl->get_value() <=> rhs->get_value();`? Where get_value returns the values you want to order by?

Comment: @PepijnKramer And how to do that without definition of `MyImpl` being available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But that heavily depends on the details of MyImpl.

No, it doesn't.

I mean yes, in a *literal* in-code sense, the details of the comparison are determined by `MyImpl`. But the comparison category of a type is *not* a private element of that type. It's a public interface, and that public interface needs to be defined.

In its entirety.

This is no different from *any* public member of a Pimpl'd type. If the type has a public interface and a private implementation, the two functions must be in sync. Any changes to one must be propagated to the other.

C++ Pimpl is not DRY. Indeed, it often involves a *lot* of redundancy. That's just the nature of the idiom.

> If MyImpl contains only ints, the return type would be std::strong_ordering, but if it would contain floats too it would be std::partial_ordering.

And you have therefore changed the *public interface* of that class. You have changed when and how the user can compare instances of that type.

This is not a private matter, so the public interface needs to change accordingly.

Comment: I'd actually put it the other way: The *class* defines the ordering properties, not the implementation details of the pimpl. Even if the implementation changes, the interface must *not* change.

Comment: @j6t: That's just how an interface is supposed to work: once an interface is deployed, the implementation isn't allowed to make changes that would break the interface.

Comment: I guess this makes a lot of sense. Was hoping for some trick I wasn't aware of maybe, but you're absolutely right that the ordering is defined by the class that wraps the impl, and not the impl.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, with the help of an abstract baseclass (interface) for the implementation class. This will allow the outer class to use the interface to the implmentation and get information out of it.

Demo : https://onlinegdb.com/8Y0hdErUA

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class_impl_itf.h
// 
// start by defining an interface for your implementation
// this allows the outer class to call functions without knowing
// its implementation yet.

class class_impl_itf
{
public:
    virtual int get_value() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual ~class_impl_itf() = default;

protected:
    class_impl_itf() = default;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class.h
// #include "class_impl_itf.h"

class class_t final
{
public:
    explicit class_t(int value);
    ~class_t() = default;

    // define the compare operator
    friend inline auto operator<=>(const class_t& lhs, const class_t& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.m_pimpl->get_value() <=> rhs.m_pimpl->get_value();
    }

private:
    // do not directly refer to the implementation class but its interface
    std::unique_ptr<class_impl_itf> m_pimpl;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class_impl.h
// #include "class_impl_itf.h"

class class_impl_t final : 
    public class_impl_itf
{
public:
    explicit class_impl_t(int value);
    int get_value() const noexcept override;

private:
private:
    int m_value;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class.cpp
// #include "class.h"
// #include "class_impl.h"

// class_t source file
class_t::class_t(int value) :
    m_pimpl{std::make_unique<class_impl_t>(value)}
{
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class_impl.cpp 
//
class_impl_t::class_impl_t(int value) :
    m_value{value}
{
}

int class_impl_t::get_value() const noexcept
{
    return m_value;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main.cpp 
// #include <class.h>
int main()
{
    class_t obj1{1};
    class_t obj2{2};

    if (obj1 < obj2)
    {
        std::cout << "obj1 < obj2";
    }

    return 0;
}
```